# What dependencies on Power8 does Anaconda5.1 have ? could it run on Power7?

Tags: anaconda

I have spare power7 capacity and was planning on running Linux/Anaconda there, wondering why 5.1 says it is for Power8.

Comment: I assume the dependency comes with the OS and little vs big indian issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

must be related to OS support for the architecture.